# Open gate effect using AJAX adjustment requested

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to adapt this tutorial: http://thefinishedbox.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/sliding-doors-jquery-tutorial/ so that it creates the effect of opening a gate when you rollover the images. I have gotten this far: http://oneonmarlin.com/slide_test/ but what I want is for both sides of the "gate", in this case the logo, to open at the same time and reveal the two underlay images. Here is the JS for the action:

```
$(function() {

$('#left').hover(function() {
    $('img.top', $(this)).stop().animate({left: '-150px'}, 500);
},function() {
    $('img.top', $(this)).stop().animate({left: '0'}, 500);
});



$('#right').hover(function() {
    $('img.top', $(this)).stop().animate({left: '150px'}, 500);
},function() {
    $('img.top', $(this)).stop().animate({left: '0'}, 500);
});

});
```

Can anyone tell me how to adapt this so that whether I put my mouse over the left or the right both sides "open"?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using separate hovers for #left and #right, wrap those elements in a div and then write one hover for that wrapper.

Comment: but I want them to go in two different directions so would I just have one hover function and two animations under?